# Memory leak with object initialized in a static method and using NSNotificationCenter

Tags: c#, ios, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, uiactivityindicatorview

For convenience, I am using a helper class that allow to display a wait indicator without needing a variable / reference into each view. The class implement a static method public

```
static void ShowActivityIndicator(UIView view, bool animated,  UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle style)
```

In this method, I am creating a DFActivity indicator and display it on the view given in parameter:

```
DFActivityIndicator activityIndicator = new DFActivityIndicator(view.Bounds);
view.AddSubview(activityIndicator);
activityIndicator.LabelText = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("Loading...", "");
activityIndicator.Indicator.ActivityIndicatorViewStyle = style;
activityIndicator.Show(true);
```

The constructor of the method is:

```
public DFActivityIndicator(RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
{      

  Indicator = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray);
  this.AddSubview(Indicator);
  Indicator.StartAnimating();
  Indicator.Frame = new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
  Indicator.StartAnimating();

  //...

  Label = new UILabel(Bounds);

  RotationTransform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity();
  NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.DidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, DeviceOrientationDidChange, this);

}
```

The observer is here to be able to rotate the indicator when the interface is rotated. When, the indicator is not anymore needed, I have an other static method:

```
 public static bool HideActivityIndicator(UIView view, bool animated)
{
  UIView viewToRemove = null;
  foreach(UIView v in view.Subviews)
  {
    if (v is DFActivityIndicator)
    {
      viewToRemove = v;
    }
  }

  if (viewToRemove != null)
  {
    DFActivityIndicator activityIndicator = viewToRemove as DFActivityIndicator;
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(activityIndicator, UIApplication.DidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, null);
    activityIndicator.RemoveFromSuperview();
    activityIndicator.Dispose();
    activityIndicator = null;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is working fine, expect the Mono profiler indicates that each time I am calling `ShowActivityIndicator`, each instance is kept into memory even if I call `HideActivityIndicator` for all instances . The memory of my application is then just increasing until crashing (seems thus be a memory leak). For debugging, I tried to remove the observer on orientation changes: 
`NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.DidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, DeviceOrientationDidChange, this)`) 
and... the code is not leaking anymore. Is it a MonoTouch bug or I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: My guess is I am not using the right AddObserver / RemoveObserver method.

Comment: So you're saying that removing the observer in HideActivityIndicator does not work, but removing the observer on orientation changes do work? The HeapShot profiler is also able to tell you which object is keeping the DFActivityIndicator alive if you click the "Inverse References" check box.

Comment: No when I am commenting 'AddObserver' and 'RemoveObserver' lines, it seems that there is no leaks anymore. The reference that seems to keep `DFActivityIndicator` alive is `System.Action<MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotification>`, kept by `MonoTouch.Foundation.InternalNSNotificationHandler` kept by `System.Collection.Generic.List<NSObject>`, kept by `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSNotificationCenter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think you are not using the AddObsever/RemoveObserver methods correctly.

Here is what you are doing with the overloads you are using:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.DidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, DeviceOrientationDidChange, this);
```

You are registering to receive notifications for status bar orientation changes, which will trigger the DeviceOrientationChange callback, **if these notifications come from** `this`. So your callback will never be triggered (since your DFActivityIndicator never posts such a notification) but, the default center (or better, the series of objects that you mentioned in the comments) will hold a reference to the view.

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(activityIndicator, UIApplication.DidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, null);
```

You are trying to remove a view instead of a notification observer. No need to explain the remaining parameters.

Here is what you should do:

```
//To add the observer:
NSObject observerObject;
//..
this.observerObject = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIApplication.DidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, DeviceOrientationDidChange)
//..
//To remove the observer:
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(this.observerObject);
```